# Closing an html5 application

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have an application built in html5 and phonegap for android, by pressing the exit button I call the following function(JavaScript):

```
function close_window() {
    if (confirm("Exit?")) {
        window.close();
    }
}
```

Window with the message "Exit?" appear, but the application does not close when you click OK, how can we close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use phonegap's

navigator.app.exitApp() to exit the application.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Write this command on phoneGap? There is no way to make it through the JavaScript?

Comment: This command is meant to be written in javascript.. You can put this command in your javascript where you need to exit the application.In your case instead of window.close() use this command

Comment: Even I tried using navigator.app.exitApp() in my javascript function, but this is not helping me out.

Comment: Even I tried using navigator.app.exitApp() in my javascript function, but this is not helping me out. I don't know what I am missing. I am using phonegap.js. Do I need to do anything more for it?